# Where is the password stored? How do I obtain a new one?

Tags: 6, database

I have installed  Drupal Commons 6.x 23, but I forgot the username/password I used for the account I created.

Where is the information stored? How can I get a new password?

Comment: If you have access in the database you can manually update it there by using this query `UPDATE users SET password=md5('YOURPASSWORD') where UID=1;` The UID should be your UID, 1 is the superuser. To know your UID do this query `SELECT uid from users where name="YOURUSERNAME";`

Comment: hello many thanks - i ll try this out. greetings zero